# REMOTE_ADDR not getting sent to Django using nginx & tornado

Tags: django, nginx, tornado

So I got a simple setup with nginx for static media and load balancing and tornado as webserver for django (4 servers running). My problem is remote_addr not getting passed on to django so I'm getting a KeyError:

`article.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`

The remote address is getting sent through as X-Real-IP (HTTP_X_REAL_IP) thanks to the nginx.conf:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect false;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://frontends;
    }
```

As HTTP is prepended to the META key I can't just do proxy_set_header remote_addr $remote_addr. What I could do is read the X-Real-IP if no remote addr key is found but I'm curious if there's a smarter solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It's no the correct solution, but I added a django middleware that turned the HTTP_X_REAL_IP into REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: These statements will help you out:
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontends;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
}
```

Just add `proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR` and it should be work well.

Tried with:

- Django 1.5.4
- Nginx 1.4.3
- Tornado 2.2.1

Comment: according this :https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip/
inside backend-nginx conf : 

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        #...other rules
}

Answer (score 17):

Here's how I solved the problem. By using this middleware:

```
class SetRemoteAddrMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.META.has_key('REMOTE_ADDR'):
            try:
                request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
            except:
                request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '1.1.1.1' # This will place a valid IP in REMOTE_ADDR but this shouldn't happen
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Only problem with this is that if you silently drop the error you will discover that misconigured web server so much later (with potentially lost information or users unable to log in). My suggestion would be to fail or at least log the error.

Comment: Almost always, you don't want to `try/except:` without exception type in CPython 2.x, because it will also catch SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt and GeneratorExit -- these are all kinds of errors you better leave alone or, in rare cases, catch them separately.
Particularly in this case, one should catch KeyError. But then you could further make all this code even simpler:
`request.META.setdefault('REMOTE_ADDR', request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', '1.1.1.1'))`

Comment: Nice solution but keep in mind has_key() was removed in Python 3.x.
Use:
if not request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None):

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar setup. After putting nginx in front of apache, I noticed that the IP in the apache logs was always 127.0.0.1. Installing "libapache2-mod-rpaf" seemed to fix it. I have no idea if your problem is related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW: This also helps PHP software, that relies on $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] which now contains the real remote IP as well.

Answer (score 5):

Add "fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;" to the nginx.conf file:

```
    location / {
    # host and port to fastcgi server
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8801;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    ...
    # Add this line!
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    ...
}
```

Source: [how to nginx virtual servers + fcgi for django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605173/how-to-nginx-virtual-servers-fcgi-for-django)

Comment: This works great for `fastcgi_pass` (thanks!), but it won't work for `proxy_pass`, which is the OP's setup (see @windyjonas' answer).

Comment: How about - `fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;`? If X-Real-IP is available to nginx, it can be used to pass-on as fastcgi_param. That will eliminate need to make changes in application source codes.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's [not possible](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,6760) to pass on remote_addr. So the only solution that I know of is to use X-Real-IP or X-Forwarded-For and make sure that the backend handles these correctly.

Edit: this applies to fastcgi_pass, not regular nginx proxy_pass

Comment: To a fastcgi handler, yes. But the question was about a nginx proxy.

Comment: Whoops, I should have read closer--`proxy_pass` is not `fastcgi_pass`. I can't repeal my downvote unless you edit your answer, apparently. :/ If you were to edit it, I'd be happy to upvote instead.

Answer (score 2):

For me, using the following worked:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.bar.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This works with django 1.4 (specifically, localshop).