# Django behind nginx: secure & robust way to get remote IP address

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django server running behind an nginx proxy. I'm currently trying to determine the remote address by reading `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`. More precisely: an app that rate-limits attempts to brute force my user's passwords (Django-brutebuster) is doing this.

Since Django is behind nginx, `REMOTE_ADDR` is the address of Nginx (127.0.0.1) so that's not really helpful. It also opens up my application to DOS by purposefully misguessing passwords since everyone is on the same IP from the perspective of brutebuster.

I've found similar questions on this forum:

- [Django get IP only returns 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512341/django-get-ip-only-returns-127-0-0-1)
- [REMOTE_ADDR not getting sent to Django using nginx & tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627901/remote-addr-not-getting-sent-to-django-using-nginx-tornado)
- [How to pass the remote IP to a proxied service? - Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880283/how-to-pass-the-remote-ip-to-a-proxied-service-nginx)

I suppose the pieces of the puzzle can be found in the above. However, I also suppose they open up the application for new vectors of attack. Specifically, automatically checking for X-something headers opens up spoofing these from the client if Django is not running behind nginx for some reason.

It's somewhat surprising to me that there appears to be no reference to "The Right & Only Way To Do This" (TM) in any of the above questions & answers. Does Django not have a canonical solution for this problem? Barring that, can we come up with a solution that does at least not create security issues?

Comment: You're trying to solve this problem in the weakest link. You should solve it as early as possible and ideally two birds with one stone, preventing bruteforce guessing and denial of service. That solution is ssh-guard and making sure that Django returns 403 on failed logons. Don't be fooled by ssh-guard name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "The Right & Only Way To Do This" (TM) is that it needs to provide instructions both to application and deployment configuration.

Django used to have a `SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor` middleware, but it was removed because "this mechanism cannot be made reliable enough for general-purpose use" (You can check the [release notes of django 1.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.1/#removed-setremoteaddrfromforwardedfor-middleware))

You described the problem correctly - you can't **generally trust** to all headers that Django app receives. The situation with such headers is too much deployment specific and that's why it lacks a general solution.

To secure such headers you need to force setting of this headers on you nginx/haproxy/whatever.